# sort a multi indexed list in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, data-structures

I have multi indexed survey data in pandas dataframe in a list format. One subset of it is given below. I am trying to sort the columns first in ascending order and than take the count of value for each rank.

`rank these items on a scale of 1-5`   `rank these items on a scale of 1-3`

```
                                               A   B   C                     
X   Y   Z
                                               1   2   1
1   2   1                                      2   3   2
2   1   3                                      1   2   3
3   1   1                                      1   1   2
5   3   2                                      2   1   3
1   1   2                                      3   1   1
NA  5   3                                      3   2   NA
4   NA  NA                                     1   3   1
1   4   4                                      2   NA  2
3   3   5`
```

I used the following code to drop NA from the data frame and take the count of values but i am not able to sort the values in ascending order before doing the count.

```
`def find_column_with_max_length(df):
    n = ''
    count = 0
    for name, values in df.iteritems():
        df[name] = pd.to_numeric(df[name], errors='coerce')
        c = len(df[name].value_counts().values.tolist())
        if c > count:
            count = c
            n = name
    return n`

    df1 = pd.DataFrame()
    df1 = df1.sort_values('n', ascending=True)
    n = find_column_with_max_length(df)
    df1[n] = pd.DataFrame(df[n].value_counts().values.tolist(), columns=[n])
    for name, values in df.iteritems():
        if name != n:
            df1[name] = pd.DataFrame(df[name].value_counts().values.tolist(),
                                        columns=[name])`
```

Any help in this regard would be greatly appreciated.